# Calculate $\oint_{\gamma} \tanh(z) dz$ on the curve $|z - \frac {\pi}{4}i|=\frac 12$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration, hyperbolic-functions

Calculate $\oint_{\gamma} \tanh(z) dz$ on the curve $|z - \frac {\pi}{4}i|=\frac 12$. I am not sure if I computed this correctly:

I tried to rewrite $\tanh(z)= \frac {\frac {e^z-e^{-z}}{2i}}{\frac {e^z+e^{-z}}2}=i\frac {1-e^{2z}}{1+e^{2z}}.$ Then tried to find the poles and found out that $e^{2z}+1= 0\implies z = i\frac {\pi}2$, but then it gave me that this pole is not inside the curve so then the integral must be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, but your argument is not correct. In fact,$$e^{2z}+1=0\iff z=\dfrac\pi2i+n\pi i\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb Z.$$However, none of these numbers belong to the regioin of $\mathbb C$ bounded by the curve and so, indeed, the integral is $0$.

Comment: what did you do to get to that answer?

Comment: I used two things. FIrst: $e^{\pi i}=-1$. Second: if $e^{z_0}=w$, then$$\{z\in\mathbb C\,|\,e^z=w\}=\{z_0+2n\pi i\,|\,n\in\mathbb Z\}.$$